# Defining a list in enum to identify enums as being part of a subgroup

Tags: python, enums

I would like to use IntEnum in Python to define a set of status codes as follows:

```
from enum import IntEnum, unique


# Modeled after HTTP Status Codes
@unique
class StatusCode(IntEnum):

    CONTINUE = 100  # Informational response: request was received and understood

    OK = 200  # Success Response: request was a success and the response depends on it. This will return an entity describing or containing the result of the action.
    CREATED = 201  # Success Response: request was a success and a document has been created
    ACCEPTED = 202  # Success Response: request was a success and is in progress

    BAD_REQUEST = 400  # Client Error: the request was not processed due to a client-side error (e.g., invalid syntax, too large, ...)
    UNAUTHORIZED = 401  # Client Error: authentication is required but has failed or has not yet been provided
    FORBIDDEN = 403  # Client Error: Client is not authorized to do the request
    NOT_FOUND = 404  # Client Error: The request is not found
    CONFLICT = 409  # Client Error: The request conflicts with the state of the server
    INTERNAL_ERROR = 500  # Server Error: has encountered an error it does not know how to handle.
```

Now, I'd also like to identify a subset of these enums as being 'successful' so that I can say somewhere, for instance, "do this if x is in subset of enums that are deemed succesful".

My initial approach was to add this code:

```
class StatusCode(IntEnum):

    SUCCESS_RESULTS = [CONTINUE, OK, CREATED, ACCEPTED]
    ...
```

However, this throws the error

```
NameError: name 'CONTINUE' is not defined
```

I think I'm misusing enums or there are better ways to do what I want.

I tried with self.Continue and StatusCode.continue but think I'm just approaching the issue wrong. Any help?

Comment: Why not have a method, e.g. `def successful(self, x): return 200 <= x.value < 400`.

Comment: Thanks, this works with some adjustments (have to add it as a classmethod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to define the list `SUCCESS_RESULTS` before you have defined the members `CONTINUE`, `OK`, `CREATED`, and `ACCEPTED`.

Move the list to the end of the block.

At that point you will get a `TypeError` complaining that a `list` cannot be converted to an `int`.

At this point I would reach for `aenum`<sup>1</sup> and its `constant` class, and do this:

```
from aenum import IntEnum, constant, unique

@unique
class StatusCode(IntEnum):
    CONTINUE = 100
    OK = 200
    CREATED = 201
    ACCEPTED = 202
    BAD_REQUEST = 400
    UNAUTHORIZED = 401
    FORBIDDEN = 403
    NOT_FOUND = 404
    CONFLICT = 409
    INTERNAL_ERROR = 500
    SUCCESS_RESULTS = constant([CONTINUE, OK, CREATED, ACCEPTED])
```

I would also change `SUCCESS_RESULTS` from a `list` to a `tuple`, because `constant` reflects the inability of `SUCCESS_RESULTS`, the name, to be deleted or rebound -- but if the object it represents is mutable, it can be mutated.

---

Now that you have `aenum`, you could also consider having `successful` be an attribute on each member instead of something you have to look up:

```
from aenum import IntEnum, constant, unique

@unique
class StatusCode(IntEnum):
    _init_ = 'value successful'
    CONTINUE = 100, True
    OK = 200, True
    CREATED = 201, True
    ACCEPTED = 202, True
    BAD_REQUEST = 400, False
    UNAUTHORIZED = 401, False
    FORBIDDEN = 403, False
    NOT_FOUND = 404, False
    CONFLICT = 409, False
    INTERNAL_ERROR = 500, False
    SUCCESS_RESULTS = constant([CONTINUE, OK, CREATED, ACCEPTED])
```

and in use:

```
>>> StatusCode.OK.successful
True

>>> StatusCode.NOT_FOUND.successful
False
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.